# How can I move these navigation items to the right?

Tags: html, css

I've created navigation with 3 items and a logo inside of it, I want the three list items to be on the right side of the page, is there any idea on how I can accomplish that?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #1f1f1f;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="IMG/straight-back-games-logo.jpg" class="logo" alt="logo of straight back games studio" width=10%>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BUY DEVOUR NOW!</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add `display: flex` to `nav` element and elements will be aligned side by side:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: #1f1f1f;
  display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <img src="img.jpg" class="logo" alt="logo of straight back games studio" width=10%>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BUY DEVOUR NOW!</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do here is float the `img` to the **left** and float the `nav ul li` to the **right**. This will cause the nav items to be in the wrong order and isn't the best solution out there, but it is the easiest and it does the job.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    background: #1f1f1f;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
        <img src="IMG/straight-back-games-logo.jpg" class="logo" alt="logo of straight back games studio" width=10%>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BUY DEVOUR NOW!</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put display: flex and justify-content: flex-end on the element immediately above your list.  So put it on the nav tag, not the header tag.  Also, there is actually no reason to have ul or li tags here - you can just put the a tags directly inside the nav tag.  And you could move the img tag outside of the nav, since it is not a nav link.  Also, put the width:10% for the image in the css - I don't think percentage widths can be specified as attributes, only pixel widths, and regardless, css is the more official way.

```
<style>
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    img.logo {
        width: 10%;
    }

    header {
        display: block;
    }

    nav {
        width: 100%;
        background: #1f1f1f;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
    }

    nav a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-right: 1.5em;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="/img/straight-back-games-logo.jpg" class="logo" alt="logo of straight back games studio">
        <nav>
            <a href="#">HOME</a>
            <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
            <a href="#">BUY DEVOUR NOW!</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
</body>
```